# Passing select option onto href in an "a" tag

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently facing some difficulties trying to pass on the value from the select option to the button. I can't figure out whats the next step.

I want to pass the value from the select option, onto the button and change the href of the a tag to "community/*value*".

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
<div class="communitycpost">
  <strong>View All Posts By:</strong><br>
  <select id="viewallposts" class="viewallposts" name="viewallposts">
    <?php
    require "includes/dbh.inc.php";
    $sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT(cpost_user) FROM cposts;";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($rows = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      $CUser = $rows['cpost_user'];
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $CUser; ?>"><?php echo $CUser; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select><br>
  <a id="viewalla" href="community/<?php echo $CUser; ?>">
    <button id="cpost_btn" class="cpost_btn" type="button"> View </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this to try and solve it! I hope it can help someone who needs it!

```
<script>
   function usrselect() {
      var usr = document.getElementById("viewallposts");
      var comm = "community/"
      var displaytext = usr.options[usr.selectedIndex].text;
      var userurl = comm + displaytext
      document.getElementById("viewalla").href = userurl;
      }
</script>
```